# UPDATE SELECT statement with XML field

Tags: sql, xml, xpath

I'm attempting to do an UPDATE statement where I need to SELECT a value from a table I join on.  The value I need to grab is part of an XML node, but I'm having difficulty getting it.  I want to grab the LocationID from the below-mentioned XML.  I edited the code and table names/fields, but the premise remains the same.

My current SQL query:

```
UPDATE table1

SET LocationId = CAST(t2.CustomProperties AS xml).value('(/ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty/@LocationId)[1]', 'varchar(36)')

FROM table1 as t1
INNER JOIN table2 as t2
ON t1.x = t2.x

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>  <ArrayOfCustomProperty xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    <CustomProperty>      <DeveloperId>X</DeveloperId>      <Key>ShipToId</Key>      <Value>X</Value>    </CustomProperty>    <CustomProperty>      <DeveloperId>X</DeveloperId>      <Key>CustomerId</Key>      <Value>X</Value>    </CustomProperty>    <CustomProperty>      <DeveloperId>X</DeveloperId>      <Key>CorporateId</Key>      <Value>X</Value>    </CustomProperty>    <CustomProperty>      <DeveloperId>X</DeveloperId>      <Key>NeedsApproval</Key>      <Value>0</Value>    </CustomProperty>    <CustomProperty>      <DeveloperId>X</DeveloperId>      <Key>LocationId</Key>      <Value>X</Value>    </CustomProperty>  </ArrayOfCustomProperty>
```

I keep getting a NULL value returned, but I can see that the LocationID does have a value.

EDIT: My Solution

```
CAST(CAST(CustomProperties AS xml).query('ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty/Key[text()="LocationId"]/../Value/text()') AS nvarchar)
```

Comment: Looks to me like your first CustomProperty node doesn't have a LocationId node, so, you are getting null

Comment: I put "X" for the sake of discretion, but the LocationId node does have a value

Comment: I provided a possible solution below.

Comment: Unfortunately, I could not get that syntax to work.  Kept getting errors around the "AS" and "CAST" portions, and decided to take a different approach.  Edited with my solution.  Thanks for the replies, though.

Comment: Ok. Glad you got it working, I asked a moderator to close this as you answered your own question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML seems to be a typical list of *key-value-pairs*.

If this is under your control, you really should store this as native XML... storing XML in strings is erronous and slow...

You can use a query like this to filter the needed value:

```sql
DECLARE @DeveloperId VARCHAR(10)='X';
DECLARE @Key VARCHAR(50)='LocationId';

SELECT CAST(t2.CustomProperties AS xml)
          .value('(/ArrayOfCustomProperty
                   /CustomProperty[(DeveloperId/text())[1]=sql:variable("@DeveloperId")
                                   and (Key/text())[1]=sql:variable("@Key")]
                   /Value
                   /text())[1]','nvarchar(max)');
```

The Path will look for a fitting `<CustomProperty>` and take its `<Values>`'s `text()`

Comment: It is not under my control, unfortunately.  I believe this particular field is done this way to be compatible with older systems and versions of our software.  Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
SET LocationId = (SELECT TOP 1 x.value('/LocationId[1]') AS [LocationId]
FROM CAST(t2.CustomProperties AS xml).nodes('/ArrayOfCustomProperty/CustomProperty') AS a(x)
WHERE x.value('/LocationId[1]') IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I probably could have made mode code a little clearer.  I have to Inner Join because CustomProperties comes from table2.  Will update the original code.

Comment: @JohnPete22 You can keep what you have for `Joining`, just replace the `SET` line with my answer. I updated to reflect your table join.